# Data binding for 20 <inputs> but only one common onchange-method

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I have a calculation sheet where the user can enter several positions (basic price, multiple options) that should be added up to a total. I am struggling in binding the events to add up all the positions to a final total. The problem is, that the @bind="" does not allow me to call one onchange events for every `input`, hence I would have to implement one event handler per position (circa 20 in total).

```
<input type="number" @bind="calc.BasicPrice" class="form-control" />
<input type="number" @bind="calc.Option" class="form-control" />

<input type="number" @bind="calc.Total" class="form-control" readonly/>

@code 
{
    private CalculationModel calc = new CalculationModel(); 
}
```

What I have tried so far is to bind a `UpdateBottomLine()` method to the input onchange events like that:

```
   <input type="number" value="@calc.BasicPrice" 
                           @onchange="(e) => CalculateBottomLines(calc.BasicPrice.GetType(), e)"  
                           class="form-control" />
    
@code {
    
    private void CalculateBottomLines(Type field, ChangeEventArgs input)
    {

            input.Value = input.Value.ToString().Replace(".", ",");

            // Update the input variable
            calc.BasicPrice = Convert.ToDecimal( input.Value.ToString() ); // <-- The name of the receiving variable has to be determined dynamically, depending on the field that was changed

            // Update the total
            calc.Total = calc.BasicPrice + calc.Option;
    }
    
}
```

Now unfortunately, while this changes my total when i change the basic price, this does not yet work dynamically but is only implemented for the basic price. I would need a solution where I can pass a reference to the field that was changed to the `CalculateBottomLines()` method.

Comment: Your total needs to add up all the values, not incrementally change when each input changes - or you will end up with the wrong total when someone changes one input multiple times. There is no need for onchange events, just bind the values that can be entered by the user, use `value=@calc.Total` instead of binding and calc.Total should be a function that adds up all the individual items `Total => BasicPrice + Option + ...`. If there is added complexity that you have not mentioned, please update your question.

Comment: I did add up all the individual positions to calculate the total. if you enter a new number in the BasicPrice field, the CalculateBottomLines method is triggered where the new total is calculated and displayed in its own field. The idea was to have the onchange events only in inputs, where the user can actually change something.

Comment: Ah right ok it's hard sometimes with fragments of code. Still use a function for the total then you don't need the event

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more what that would look like? Can't follow you here... I have to trigger that "UpdateTotal" method everytime someone changes a value either for BasicPrice or one of the 20 options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am using the property setter to recalculate the total and `@bind:event="oninput"` to trigger on input.

```
<input type="number" @bind="calc.BasicPrice" @bind:event="oninput" class="form-control" />
<input type="number" @bind="calc.Option" @bind:event="oninput" class="form-control" />
<input type="number" @bind="calc.Total" class="form-control" readonly />

@code {
    SomeModel calc = new SomeModel();
    public class SomeModel
    {
        public double BasicPrice
        {
            get => basicPrice;
            set { basicPrice = value; UpdateTotal(); }
        }
        public double Option
        {
            get => option;
            set { option = value; UpdateTotal(); }
        }

        public double Total { get; set; }

        internal void UpdateTotal()
        {
            Total = BasicPrice + Option;
        }

        private double basicPrice;
        private double option;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it the way Brian explained but i get an Access violation as soon as i type something in the basicprice (or any other) field: r
The program '[17028] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Comment: @d00d Here is a working repo with the above code pasted... https://github.com/BrianLParker/DataBindingStackQuestion

Comment: Yes thanks, I just tried that with a fresh file. It works for me, but gives me that access violation trouble in my regular razor file. Will have to find out what the problem is. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Okay, I could find my error. I had the UpdateTotal function connected to the setter of Total, which led to an infinite loop...